# What is the relation between difraction and energy levels?

Tags: energy, photons, diffraction, atoms

Imagine I have an atom in the cold space. The energy gap between its current energy and the next is exactly equals to the photons energy that is about to meet an atom. Atom absorbs photon. All is fine, except one thing - absorbed photons wavelength was 500 nm.

How could atom absorb this photon if it's sizes is a few times tinier then photons wavelength(atom had to be 'invisible' for photon)?

Answer (score 1):

The sound you hear also has a wavelength that is much larger than your ear. The wavelength of a photon is not its size but contains information about its energy and momentum.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could think of it as while the electron is moving inside the atom it takes a certain time, use time = distance over velocity.  Thus 500nm divided by the speed of light is 167 times 10 to the -17, which is a very short time but could be the reason it can occur.